# Friends Pair Algorithm Recursive solution in C

Tags: c, algorithm

> Given n friends, each one can remain single or can be paired up with
>   some other friend. Each friend can be paired only once. Find out the
>   total number of ways in which friends can remain single or can be
>   paired up. Examples: Input  : n = 3 Output : 4
>
> Explanation: [{1}, {2}, {3} : all single ]
>                  [{1}, {2,3}] : 2 and 3 paired  but 1 is single] 
>   similarly
>                  [{1,2}, {3}]
>                  [{1,3}, {2}]
>
> finally answer 4

here I'm stuck to construct the recursion

```
int friends(int i)
{
    if(i==0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(i==1){
        return 1;
    }
    friends(i)=friends(i-1)+(i-1)*friends(i-2);
}
```

For further reference : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friends-pairing-problem/

Comment: Please explain in detail what makes you think that you have a problem? Apart from the obvious lack of another `return` at the end of the function and the strange construct where it should be.

Comment: This line is invalid `friends(i)=friends(i-1)+(i-1)*friends(i-2);` Maybe you want something like `return friends(i-1)+(i-1)*friends(i-2);` I'm not sure the algorithm is correct, though.

Comment: I'm not getting the answer I want but atleast the recursion worked -4386427. Would you please look up the link I provided?

Comment: Note that there are competent and usually very helpful people here, who simply refuse following links. For a better chance to a satisfying answer take the time to put all needed information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing return statement

```
return friends(i-1)+(i-1)*friends(i-2);
```

and as code from link says, there is

```
if (i <= 2)
           dp[i] = i;
```

and you are missing i == 2 in your code

for example this recursion works, I do not know what do you need to know more:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int friends(int i)
{
    if(i<=2)
        return i;
    return friends(i-1)+(i-1)*friends(i-2);
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d", friends(3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Still I'm not getting the answer would you please look up to this link and help to construct the recusrsion ? http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friends-pairing-problem/

Comment: @StackQueue Note that there are competent and usually very helpful people here, who simply refuse following links. For a better chance to a satisfying answer take the time to put all needed information in your question.

Comment: @Yunnosch  exactly. Upvoted

Comment: @Angen  that's the DP solution and OP is asking for recursive solution may be

Comment: Wit the code dp[i] <=2 I was trying to explain that he is missing if(i == 2) return  2 in his code based on idea from the link

Comment: Worked Finally Angen